# How to document a Hasura GraphQL API

Tags: hasura

My googling is surely failing me, but how would one document the fields and types in a GraphQL API produced by Hasura?

Comment: The metadata is kept in a Yaml file. Should not be too hard to parse and output into some format if you were so inclined... https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/index/#hasura-metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since field and types are auto-generated, documentation for them is taken from comments added to Tables and Columns. You can find them on the console as well as add to metadata yaml. These comments will then appear on the generated GraphQL schema.

See comments key in the example [here](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/api-reference/metadata-api/table-view/#metadata-pg-track-table).